# Write code with with type hint Optional[TYPE] which gets accepted by mypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I am currently using the following line in my classes to instantiate a member variable that is set at a later point in time:

```py
self._remaining_time_calculator: Optional[RemainingTimeCalculator] = None
```

After some input from the user, I can then determine which instance of the RemainingTimeCalculator I need to create. For example:

```py
self._remaining_time_calculator = RemainingTimeCalculator(
    type = Type1
    some_value_which_is_used_in_calculation = 10.0
)
```

Later in the code, when I want to update the `some_value_which_is_used_in_calculation` attribute, mypy complains:

`Mypy: Item "None" of "Optional[RemainingTimeCalculator]" has no attribute "some_value_which_is_used_in_calculation" [union-attr]`.

I know that mypy is pure static code analysis and therefore it cannot know that the optional instance variable is always set before changing the value if `some_value_which_is_used_in_calculation`.

My question is, how can I write code that mypy will accept in this case?

Comment: Use type narrowing. Statically, if `x` has type `Optional[Foo]`, then `if x is not None: reveal_type(x)` will produce `Foo`, because `mypy` can tell statically that the runtime type of `x` must be `Foo`, not `NoneType`, or else `reveal_type` would not be executed.

Comment: Need more context and detail to post a proper answer.

Comment: Currently I have a large class that abstracts some functionality and it stores some data that is only available to the runtime as it is provided by user input. However, in order to retrieve the data later at other points in the project, I want to store it within the class instance. To achieve this I need to use this "trick" to set the member variable to None. This works fine, but breaks if I later use a variable of that None member variable elsewhere in the project. Because mypy thinks the varibale is None and does not have the attribute I want to change.

Comment: If you are certain that `_remaining_time_calculator` cannot be `None` when it is used, you can write `assert _remaining_time_calculator is not None` to narrow the type and avoid a runtime check (or to avoid having to handle the "if None" case).

Comment: You could also not initialize the variable with `None` and annotate it with `RemainingTimeCalculator` instead of `Optional[RemainingTimeCalculator]` (in the class body, not in `__init__`: `_remaining_time_calculator: RemainingTimeCalculator`)

Comment: @mkrieger1 this works. Is this a better approach then `if some_value_which_is_used_in_calculation: some_value_which_is_used_in_calculation = 12.0`

Comment: No, if you are reassigning the variable anyway, you don't need a check.

Comment: Why not inside the `__init__`? It should be an instance variable and not a class variable.

Comment: Why is it optional in the first place? If it's just so you can properly initialize it later, it may be better to simply wait until you *can* initialize the attribute to instantiate the class, so that it never has type `Optional[...]` in the first place.

Comment: @chepner But then it warns me that I am initialising a member variable outside the `__init__` block, which is why I came up with the `Optional[...]` code in the first place.

Comment: I didn't say to initialize the attribute outside `__init__`; I said wait until you have the actual `RemainingTimeCalculator` object to *create* the object that needs it.